# Train a point rather than a bounding box for object detection

Tags: object-detection

In the graph below, object detection is done through a point that points to the right place rather than a bounding box (e.g., using faster RCNN). What method enables to  train such a point?

[image: Wbha]

Answer (score 0):

Ususally the x,y coordinates of the top-left corner of the bounding box and the width and height of the bounding box is returned by objection detection algorithms (eg: Haar Cascades)

You can always convert a bounding box to a point via the equation:

> $BoundingBoxCenter_{x}= \frac{BoundingBoxCorner_{x} +
>  BoundingBoxWidth}{2}$
> $BoundingBoxCenter_{y}=
>  \frac{BoundingBoxCorner_{y} + BoundingBoxHeight}{2}$